# How to allow one server-side session per user in flask?

Tags: python, session, flask

I have a flask applicaton with global authorization for whole application using **flask-login** module:

```
from flask import url_for, g
from flask.ext.login import login_user, logout_user, current_user
def check_authenticate():
    g.user = current_user
    if not g.user.is_authenticated() \
        and request.endpoint != 'authorization.login' \
        and request.endpoint != 'static':
            logout_user()
            return redirect(url_for('authorization.login', path=request.path))
app = Flask(__name__)
app.before_request(check_authenticate)
```

Now i am using default session interface which stores all session params in cookies. I want to setup server-side sessions for my app i found a snippet for that http://flask.pocoo.org./snippets/86/

The problem is i want to allow one session per user. How to organize it? What architecture should be? I guess I should create additional columns for table with users - session_id and session_params and modify the snippet above but what should i do with anonymous users? Where should i store sessions for them?